# iOS : Cancel a Void function

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode, ipad

I have created a method for example `changeColor` for calling the method we use

```
[self changeColor];
```

but how can I cancel these method ?

Edited : 
here is my code I have several buttons which they add some image to the image view

```
- (void) setImagesFrame1 {


        NSMutableArray *imageArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithCapacity:12];
        for (int i = 0; i <= 12; i++) {
        NSString *fileName = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"a%d.png",i];
        UIImage *j = [UIImage imageNamed:fileName];
        UIImageView *tempImage = [[UIImageView alloc]initWithImage:j];
        [imageArray addObject:tempImage];
        [self createPageWithImage:tempImage forPage:i];

    }


}


- (void) setImagesFrame2 {


        NSMutableArray *imageArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithCapacity:12];
        for (int i = 0; i <= 12; i++) {
        NSString *fileName = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"s%d.png",i];
        UIImage *j = [UIImage imageNamed:fileName];
        UIImageView *tempImage = [[UIImageView alloc]initWithImage:j];
        [imageArray addObject:tempImage];
        [self createPageWithImage:tempImage forPage:i];

    }


}
```

and so on ...

I call my methods with this action :

```
- (IBAction)openFrames:(UIButton *)sender {


    [captureView addSubview:framesPreviewView];
    [framesPreviewView sendSubviewToBack:captureView];
    framesPreviewView.frame = CGRectMake(img.bounds.origin.x, img.bounds.origin.y, img.bounds.size.width,  img.bounds.size.height);

        //buttons 
    if (sender == frame1) { [self setImagesFrame1];   }
    if (sender == frame2) {  NSLog(@"frame2"); }
    if (sender == frame3) { [self setImagesFrame3]; NSLog(@"frame3"); }


}
```

when I press frame1 button the images  will be added to my view , the problem is when I press frame2 button the images of this method also add to my view  I need avoid this situation , it means when I touch every button the methods of other button should be canceled

Comment: What do you mean by 'cancel'? How was the function invoked? Have you heard of the `return` keyword?

Comment: Please explain what you mean by cancel?

Comment: Cancel from Within the function or cancel from outside the function?

Comment: Also show us your changeColor code

Comment: I mean when this method is is running , I should cancel it outside of the function with button for example

Comment: So you want to kill a thread in mid execution from another thread? I don't think that is the approach you want to take. Please give more information regarding your business case and post some code. There is likely a simpler solution to the problem you are facing.

Comment: seems like issue with your if conditions, otherwise it won't need to call all the if?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The last view on your subview array will be the image, You should use the method [view removeFrom superView]; 
However, to do that you need to use fast enumeration(for-In loop) over the subviews array.
If you want to be completely sure , you can check the retuned object, if it belongs to UIImageView Class. Then you should execute remaining statements in you setImages method.

Example: `
               UIView *tempView;

```
           for(tempView in self.subviews) {

           if([tempView isKindOfClass:[UIImageView class] ]){
            [tempView removeFromSuperView];

          }
       }
```

`

Answer (score 2):

To leave a void function execute the return statement...

```
return;
```

Comment: where exactly should I put this code ? for example one button executes the function and another cancel it

Comment: Please post some code and detail regarding the functionality you are trying to implement.

Answer (score 0):

You can:

- disable frame2 button when frame1 is pressed
- enable frame2 button when setImagesFrame1 ended

Something like this:

```
- (void) setImagesFrame1 {
    frame2.enabled = NO;

    [... your code ...]

    frame2.enable;
}
```

So if someone press button 1, he can't press button 2 (and redraw something) until all operations are completed.